# Access control of a Module in Yii2

Tags: authentication, module, yii2, rbac

I am having a trouble with login part. 
I read this topic : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user/ . 
Then i follow its steps, but in step 6. it only configs for just one Controller. I have a Module called Admin with many controllers in it and i don't know how to apply this access control to the whole module. Can anyone help me ?
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `AdminController` class, which will extends `yii\web\Controller` where you define your access rules in `behaviors` method and make other module controllers extend your `AdminController` and override `behaviors` method like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Here `parent::behaviors()` are behaviors from `AdminController` which define default access rules, and you merge them with specific behaviors in your child controller. It gives you flexibility to override some access rules if you need.

Comment: So Yii2 Module doesn't have behaviors method, right ?

Comment: @user1571234 it has, and if you want to have access rules for entire module and none of its controllers will have different access rules you can define them in module's `behaviors` method. Defining access rules in parent controller and inheriting them gives you more flexibility if you need different behavior for some of your controllers

Answer (score 2):

I can propose a variation of the method from the article that you mentioned.
Make first 2 steps as it was described and then do the following:

**1.** Add the field `role` to User model and evaluate it with thevalue of one of the constants from the article's example (User::ROLE_ADMIN or User::ROLE_USER)

**2.** Override the yii\web\User->can()

```
public function can($permissionName, $params = [], $allowCaching = true)
{
    /** @var \app\models\User $user */
    $user = $this->identity;
    $access = false;
    do {
        if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            break;
        }

        if ($user->role === \common\models\User::ROLE_ADMIN) {
            $access = true;
            break;
        }

        if (is_array($permissionName)) {
            $access = in_array($user->role, $permissionName);
        } else {
            $access = $permissionName === $user->role;
        }
    } while (false);

    return $access;
}
```

So now you can check user's role like this:

```
\Yii::$app->user->can(User::ROLE_USER)
```

**3.** You say:

> i don't know how to apply this access control to the whole module.

Then open your module class and add the following to the behaviors() method:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => [User::ROLE_ADMIN]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

In this example we grant access to ROLE_ADMIN to all actions of all controllers of your module.
That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom model `AccessRules.php` as shown below:

```
<?php 
namespace app\models;


class AccessRules extends \yii\filters\AccessRule
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function matchRole($user)
    {
        if (empty($this->roles)) {
            return true;
        }
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            if ($role === '?') {

                if ($user->getIsGuest()) {
                    return true;
                }
            } elseif ($role === '@') {
                if (!$user->getIsGuest()) {
                    return true;
                }
            // Check if the user is logged in, and the roles match
            } elseif (!$user->getIsGuest() && (int)$role === $user->identity->user_role) {
               return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Now open your site controller and add the following code in fuction behavior part:

```
use app\models\AccessRules;
 public function behaviors()
   {
        return [
            'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    // We will override the default rule config with the new AccessRule class
    'ruleConfig' => [
        'class' => AccessRules::className(),
    ],
    'only' => ['create', 'update', 'delete','index'],
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['create', 'update', 'delete','index'],
            'allow' => true,
            // Allow admin to create
            'roles' => [
                '1' 
            ],
        ]
    ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: for the sake of clarity, you used `user_role`. The column `role` is created with a default value of `10`, when using Yii2 advanced and running migrations. Not that you can't change it :) Just in case someone else stumbles here, I wanted that difference to be noted.

Answer (score 1):

According to The [Yii2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)
"ACF is an action filter that can be used in a controller or a module" in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in controller which you want to restrict functionality

```
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),

            'rules' => 
            [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index','view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@']
                ],

                [
                    'actions' => ['create','update','delete'],                            
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],

                     'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) 
                     {
                            return Admin::isUserAdmin(Yii::$app->user->identity->username);
                    }
                ],
             ],

        ],
```